# Attaching multiple uitextfields to an email

Tags: uitextfield, xcode4.3, email-attachments

I have multiple UITextFields and I want to attach them to an in app email.  I can get one of them appear but not the rest.  Here is what I am using.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[composer setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[composer setMessageBody:AddNotesTextField.text isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];

[composer release];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right already for the body using:

```
[composer setMessageBody:AddNotesTextField.text isHTML:YES];
```

So just repeat the procedure with the other fields like so:

```
[composer setSubject:mySubjectTextField.text];
```

Or if you are asking how to use the input from multiple text fields into the body of the email, you simply have to use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat`:

```
[composer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you can place static %@ text in between %@ these variables",AddNotesTextField.text,someOtherField.text] isHTML:YES];
```

In string with format, you escape the default string to add a string using "%@" for every instance where you want to insert some other string. Then after the original string ends you enter the names of the input strings separated by commas. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",x,y]`

Comment: Thank you.  I added the \n for line breaks and changed the isHTML:Yes to NO which allowed me to show the line breaks in the email.